# Distance objective optimisation

Tags: python, optimization, model, pyomo

I'm modeling a reoptimisation model and I would like to include a constraint in order to reduce the distance between the initial solution and the reoptimized solution. I'm doing a staff scheduling and to do so I wanna penalized each assignment in the reoptimized solution that is different from the initial solution.

Before I start, I'm new to optimisation model and the way I built the constraint may be wrong.

```
#1 Extract the data from the initial solution of my main variable

ModelX_DictExtVal = model.x.extract_values()

# 2 Create a new binary variable which activate when the main variable `ModelX_DictExtVal[x,s,d]` of the initial 
#solution is =1 (an employee n works days d and sifht s) and the value of `model.x[n,s,d]` of the reoptimized solution are different.  

model.alpha_distance = Var(model.N_S_D, within=Binary)

#3 Model a constraint to activate my variable.

def constraint_distance(model, n, s, d):
    v = ModelX_DictExtVal[n,s,d]
    if v == 1 and ModelX_DictExtVal[n,s,d] != model.x[n,s,d]:
        return model.alpha_distance[n,s,d] == 1
    elif v == 0:
        return model.alpha_distance[n,s,d] == 0
        
model.constraint_distance = Constraint(model.N_S_D, rule = constraint_distance)

#4 Penalize in my objective function every time the varaible is equal to one

ObjFunction = Objective(expr = sum(model.alpha_distance[n,s,d] * WeightDistance
                        for n in model.N for s in model.S for d in model.D))
```

Issue: I'm not sure about what I'm doing in part 3 and I get an index error when `v == 1`.

```
ERROR: Rule failed when generating expression for constraint
    constraint_distance with index (0, 'E', 6): ValueError: Constraint
    'constraint_distance[0,E,6]': rule returned None
```

I am wondering since I am reusing the same model for re-optimization if the model keeps the value of the initial solution of `model.x [n, s, d]` to do the comparison `ModelX_DictExtVal [n, s, d]! = model.x [n, s, d]` during the re-optimization phase instead of the new assignments...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right to suspect part 3.  :)

So you have some "initial values" that could be either the original schedule (before optimizing) or some other preliminary optimization.  And your decision variable is binary, indexed by [n,s,d] if I understand your question.

In your constraint you **cannot** employ an if-else structure based on a comparison test of your decision variable.  The value of that variable *is unknown* at the time the constraint is **built**, right?

You are on the right track, though.  So, what you really want to do is to have your `alpha_distance` (or `penalty`) variable capture any changes, indicating 1 where there is a change.  That is an absolute value operation, but can be captured with 2 constraints.  Consider (in pseudocode):

```
penalty = |x.new - x.old|    # is what you want
```

So introduce **2** constraints, (indexed fully by [n,s,d]):

```
penalty >= x.new - x.old
penalty >= x.old - x.new
```

Then, as you are doing now, include the `penalty` in your objective, optionally multiplied by a weight.

Comment back if that doesn't make sense...

Comment: Everything make sens and it works perfectly, thank you for your answer :)